# SSIS Bulk XML Import

Tags: sql, xml, ssis

I think I may be a bit over my head on this one for what my sql skills are. I have an xml file that is almost 3GB large. I need a process to import this data and insert it into tables. When I try to use SSIS xml source it complains about the XSD being complex with multiple data types. I then tried to convert the xml to csv using XLST.

I have a link to my skydrive below where I have teh XSD since I could not upload documents here. I am looking for guidance and advice on how to get this data into sql. Any help is appreciated.

https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=d75b2e7f757393ef&sc=documents&id=D75B2E7F757393EF%21286

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The built in XML components in SSIS are relatively limited.  For a larger, more complex XML source you might consider pulling the file in a script task and shredding using C#

Answer (score 1):

You can bulk insert any size XML file using [DataStreams](http://www.csvreader.com/code/cs/bulk_insert_xml.php) and SqlBulkCopy.

Answer (score 0):

In your schema, do you have any complex types that have **mixed="true"** defined?  SSIS does not support this. You would need to change your content model on complex types to not be mixed, or preprocess the documents with an XSLT.

Try running the XSLT by removing mixed="true" for testing before you invest time in pre-processing.